# How to Synchronize Client State Transitions in a Python Client-Server Game Application

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm developing a client-server game application in Python. Here's the scenario:

```
Clients connect to the server and register.
After registration, all clients see a main menu.
One client can initiate a game, selecting a number of players (x).
The selected clients should transition to an in-game state and receive new messages related to the game.
```

Issue:

The client that initiates the game transitions into the in-game state immediately. However, the other selected clients are still waiting for user input in the main menu. Once they provide input, they then transition to the in-game state. I want all selected clients to transition to the in-game state simultaneously.

"Server" Program:

```
import random
from threading import Thread
import socket
import json
import sys 

from game import Card, Game

game_state = {'player_data': {}, 'games': {}}
client_connections = {}
class Manager():
    STATE_MAIN_MENU = 'main_menu'
    STATE_IN_GAME = 'in_game'
    def __init__(self):
        self.playerList = {}
        self.games = {}
        self.player_states = {}
        self.game_id_counter = 0

    def set_state(self, player, state):
        self.player_states[player] = state

    def get_state(self, player):
        return self.player_states.get(player, self.STATE_MAIN_MENU)

    def update(self, new_state):
        self.__dict__.update(new_state)
        if 'player_data' in new_state:
            self.playerList = new_state['player_data']
        if 'games' in new_state:
            self.games = new_state['games']

    def register(self, player, ip4, mport, rport, pport, game_state):
        if player in self.playerList:
            return "FAILURE"
        self.playerList[player] = {'ip4': ip4, 'mport': mport, 'rport': rport, 'pport': pport}
        game_state['player_data'][player] = {'ip4': ip4, 'mport': mport, 'rport': rport, 'pport': pport}
        self.set_state(player, self.STATE_MAIN_MENU)
        return "SUCCESS"

    def start_game(self, dealer, k, game_state):
        k = int(k)  # Make sure k is an integer
        if dealer not in self.playerList or len(self.playerList) < k or k > 5:
            print(dealer + "DEALERINFO\n")
            for x in self.playerList:
                print(x + "HELP")
            print(f"Comparing dealer '{dealer}' with playerList keys {list(self.playerList.keys())}")
            return "FAILURE", None

        available_players = [player for player in self.playerList.keys() if self.get_state(player) != self.STATE_IN_GAME and player != dealer]
        selected_players = random.sample(available_players, k - 1)

        self.game_id_counter += 1
        game = Game(dealer, selected_players, self.playerList)

        # Setup the logical ring for the gam
        game.setup_logical_ring()

        self.games[self.game_id_counter] = game
        game_state['games'][self.game_id_counter] = {'dealer': dealer,
                                                     'players': {key: self.playerList[key] for key in selected_players}}

        # Update player states
        for player in selected_players:
            self.set_state(player, self.STATE_IN_GAME)
        self.set_state(dealer, self.STATE_IN_GAME)

        # Notify players in the new game
        for player_name in selected_players:
            player_conn = client_connections.get(player_name)
            if player_conn:
                player_conn.sendall(generate_message('YOU ARE NOW IN A GAME!!!!!!!'))

        return "SUCCESS"

    def query_players(self):
        if len(self.playerList) == 0:
            return "There are no players!"
        else:
            player_count = len(self.playerList)
            player_info_list = []

            for player_name in self.playerList.keys():
                state = self.player_states.get(player_name, "")
                if "IN_GAME" in state:
                    player_info_list.append(f"{player_name}\tIN GAME")
                else:
                    player_info_list.append(player_name)

            formatted_players = "\n".join(player_info_list)

            print("PLAYER STATES")
            for x in self.player_states:
                print(x + " " + self.player_states[x])
            print("\n")
            return f"Total players: {player_count}\nPlayers:\n{formatted_players}"

    def query_games(self):
        if len(self.games) == 0:
            return "There are no games!"
        else:
            game_count = len(self.games)
            game_list = []
            for game_id, game in self.games.items():
                dealer = game.dealer
                players = ", ".join(game.players)
                game_list.append(f"Game ID: {game_id}, Dealer: {dealer}, Players: {players}")

            formatted_games = "\n".join(game_list)
            return f"Total games: {game_count}\nGames:\n{formatted_games}"

    def dereg(self, player, game_state):
        if player in self.playerList:
            del self.playerList[player]
            if player in game_state['player_data']:
                del game_state['player_data'][player]
            return "SUCCESS"
        return "FAILURE"

def state_main_menu(conn, manager, clientName):
    msg = generate_message(
        '1: Register\n2: Start Game\n3: Query Players\n4: Query Games\n5: De-register Player\n6: Exit',
        True)
    conn.sendall(msg)
    choice = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

    if choice == '1':
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Please enter your name:', True, 'register'))

        client_data_json = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
        try:
            client_data = json.loads(client_data_json)
            clientName = client_data.get('name', '')
            ip4 = client_data.get('ip4', '')
            mport = client_data.get('mport', '')
            rport = client_data.get('rport', '')
            pport = client_data.get('pport', '')
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Invalid JSON received for registration. Ignoring.")
        result = manager.register(clientName, ip4, mport, rport, pport, game_state)
        if result == "SUCCESS":
            for player, info in game_state['player_data'].items():
                print(f"Player: {player}")
                print(f"  IP Address: {info['ip4']}")
                print(f"  mport: {info['mport']}")
                print(f"  rport: {info['rport']}")
                print(f"  pport: {info['pport']}")
            print(manager.query_players())
            return clientName

    elif choice == '2':
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Please enter your name:', True))
        playerName = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

        conn.sendall(generate_message('Please enter the amount of players:', True))
        numPlayers = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

        result = manager.start_game(playerName, numPlayers, game_state)
        if result == "SUCCESS":
            print(manager.query_games())

        else:
            conn.sendall(generate_message('Unable to start game.'))

    elif choice == '3':
        print(manager.query_players())
        conn.sendall(generate_message(manager.query_players()))

    elif choice == '4':
        print(manager.query_games())
        conn.sendall(generate_message(manager.query_games()))

    elif choice == '5':
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Are you sure you want to de-register a player?\n1: Yes\n2: No', True))
        leaveMessage = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

        while True:
            if leaveMessage == '1':
                conn.sendall(generate_message('Enter the player being de-registered:', True))
                playerGone = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
                result = manager.dereg(playerGone, game_state)
                if result == "SUCCESS":
                    conn.sendall(generate_message('PLAYER DE REG!'))
                break
            elif leaveMessage == '2':
                break
            else:
                conn.sendall(generate_message('Invalid selection, try again\n 1: Yes\n 2: No', True))
                leaveMessage = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
    else:
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Invalid choice. Try again.'))
    return clientName

def state_in_game(conn, manager, clientName):
    msg = generate_message('In-Game: 1: Play Card\n2: Quit', True)
    conn.sendall(msg)
    choice = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
    if(choice == '1'):
        print("card dealt\n")
        pass
    elif(choice == '2'):
        print("GG\n")
        manager.set_state(clientName, manager.STATE_MAIN_MENU)
        pass
    # TODO: Add the logic for handling in-game actions
    pass

def handle_client(conn, addr, manager):
    try:
        print(f"Connected to {addr}")
        clientName = None  # unique identifier for the client

        while True:
            print(f"{clientName}  CLIENT")
            if clientName:
                state = manager.get_state(clientName)
                client_connections[clientName] = conn
            else:
                state = manager.STATE_MAIN_MENU

            if state == manager.STATE_IN_GAME:
                state_in_game(conn, manager, clientName)
            else:
                clientName = state_main_menu(conn, manager, clientName)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling client {addr}: {e}")

def generate_message(message, expect_reply=False, msg_type=None):
    msg_dict = {'message': message, 'expect_reply': expect_reply}
    if msg_type:
        msg_dict['type'] = msg_type
    return json.dumps(msg_dict).encode('utf-8')

def start_server(host, port, manager):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)  # Allow up to 5 pending connections
    server_socket.settimeout(1)  # 1-second timeout
    print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")

    try:
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
            except socket.timeout:
                continue

            print(f"Connection from {addr}")
            t1 = Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr, manager))
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nShutting down server.")
        server_socket.close()
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python manager.py <port>")
        sys.exit(1)

    port = int(sys.argv[1])
    manager = Manager()
    start_server('0.0.0.0', port, manager)  # Listen on all available interfaces
```

"Client" Program:

```
import socket
import sys
import json
import random

class Client():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect((host, port))

    def run(self):
        try:
            print(f"Connected to {self.host}:{self.port}")

            # Automatically set IP and random ports
            ip4 = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
            mport = random.randint(5000, 6000)
            rport = random.randint(6001, 7000)
            pport = random.randint(7001, 8000)

            while True:
                received_data = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if not received_data:
                    print("No data received. Connection might be closed.")
                    break

                json_data = json.loads(received_data)
                print(f"Server says:\n{json_data['message']}")

                if json_data.get('expect_reply', True):
                    client_input = input("Your input: ")
                    if json_data.get('type') == 'register':
                        client_input = json.dumps({
                            'name': client_input,
                            'ip4': ip4,
                            'mport': mport,
                            'rport': rport,
                            'pport': pport
                        })
                    self.client_socket.sendall(client_input.encode('utf-8'))

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Client error: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python client.py <server_ip> <server_port>")
        sys.exit(1)

    server_ip = sys.argv[1]
    server_port = int(sys.argv[2])

    client_instance = Client(server_ip, server_port)
    client_instance.run()
```

What I've Tried:

I attempted to use multithreading on the client side to handle I/O and server messages, but it didn't solve the issue.
Expected Output:

Both clients should receive the in-game message immediately after the game is initiated.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to synchronize the client state transitions?

[image: Code output]

The expected output would be fore both of the clients to receive that message after the game is initiated.  The states are correctly updated, I am pretty sure it is because the client is stuck on this part of the code, but I would like some feedback on it.

```
 if json_data.get('expect_reply', True):
                    client_input = input("Your input: ")
                    if json_data.get('type') == 'register':
                        client_input = json.dumps({
                            'name': client_input,
                            'ip4': ip4,
                            'mport': mport,
                            'rport': rport,
                            'pport': pport
                        })
                    self.client_socket.sendall(client_input.encode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks!